# Android studio configure c++ project checkbox

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, checkbox, android-ndk

I am using Android studio for Andorid ndk.
I follow instruction: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

I have Android studio 2.1.2.
I didn't find a first step to select a checkbox with c & C++.

Attached image for the same.[image]

Do you have any idea to find this checkbox button?

Comment: Did  fix the issue with Android version update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have that checkbox either with Android Studion 2.1.3. I updated Android Studio to 2.2.2 and now I have the checkbox.

[image]

[image]

I also blogged about this to http://rapidprogrammer.com/android-studio-include-c-support-checkbox-is-missing.